# BeautifulSoup's findall with a list of names does not find targets after another target

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Other questions with similar titles did not answer my question.

If I execute this:

```
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><body><p>111</p><p>before<ul><li>222</li></ul>after</p></body></html>", "lxml")
soup.find_all(["p", "li"])
```

I get this result:

```
[<p>111</p>, <p>before</p>, <li>222</li>]
```

I expected to find "after" in the result as well, either as part of the second "p" element or as a 4th item in the list.

**Is this expected behaviour? Is there a way to retrieve the text "after"?**

More weirdness, if I do `print(soup.prettify())`, this is the result.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   111
  </p>
  <p>
   before
  </p>
  <ul>
   <li>
    222
   </li>
  </ul>
  after
 </body>
</html>
```

The "ul" and "after" are no longer part of the second "p". I assume that the source is not valid html (?), but again:

**Is there a way to deal with this, except from just dropping "after"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use different parser than `lxml` in this case: `html.parser`. `lxml` is more strict than `html.parser`:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><body><p>111</p><p>before<ul><li>222</li></ul>after</p></body></html>", "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all(["p", "li"]))
```

Prints:

```
[<p>111</p>, <p>before<ul><li>222</li></ul>after</p>, <li>222</li>]
```